# email validation javascript behaving differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I'm trying to validate a email id using javascript.

Here is the code:

```
 if (!email) {
        alert('empty value');
} else if (!ValidateEmail(email)) {
        alert('invalid email');
}
```

My [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWqmF/)

It works fine, so i thought why not make both condition into a single condition

```
    if ((!email) && (!ValidateEmail(email))) {
        alert('Invalid value');
}
```

But this time the above script doesn't work. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2P7mK/1/)

Can any one explain why its behaving so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((email) && (!ValidateEmail(email)))
```

this should be the condition!! There is no point in validating an empty email, right! hence this condition (says when there is some email(not empty) value but it is not a valid one) besides in `&&` if any one condition is `false` the final answer is `false`

and to check for empty email and alert a proper msg for that, you will have to keep the first condition!

Answer (score 0):

These two conditions are distinct. The reason the script doesn't work anymore is because BOTH conditions are not always met! One Can be, but not the other one at the same time! In your first code example, you only do the validation IF the email variable is false or not set. In other words leave it as it was!

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` (as well as `node.value`) return string so if your input is blank it will return an empty string

Empty string evaluated as true in JavaScript.

from your fiddle you can simply get rid of `(!email)` since empty string won't match your validation anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It will be really easy, If you use Jquery here an Example:-

```
var emailpattern = /^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9_\-])+([\.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*\@((([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.){1,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,40})$/;

if(!emailpattern.test($('#email').val())){
   return false;
   } else {
     return true;
  }
```